# Show weeks instead of days into month view, full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to put weeks instead of days into month view, I don't know if this is possible with full calendar but i assume that it could be done, so instead of days like in the photo above [image: Current]

it should look like this one [image: Needed View]

and this is my code that i use to initialize full calendar

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        defaultDate: '2017-11-12',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views

        weekNumbers: true,
        weekNumbersWithinDays: true,
        weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO',

        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2017-11-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2017-11-07',
                end: '2017-11-10'
            },

            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2017-11-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2017-11-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2017-11-12T12:00:00'
            },

            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: '2017-11-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2017-11-28'
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

[image]

Comment: Link to the plugin that you are using, show your current code, ..

Comment: provide some code examples please

Comment: i use fullcalendar.js , and i edited my question you can see my code

Comment: this isn't possible. There'd be no way to tell which day each event was for. An event is defined by both the day it's on, and the time it takes place. So you need the day in there somehow. The list view style (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list_view/intro/) is a _little bit_ closer to what you're thinking of, but it still won't group the weeks into columns unfortunately. Perhaps you'll have to make a custom view (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/) but this is very complex to achieve.

Comment: The only other hack would be to place several fullCalendar instances side-by-side in your layout, each displaying in "listWeek" view, configured to a different week of the month. Then you'd need a header above it with your own buttons to allow moving from one month to another, and custom code to work out the start/end of the weeks in each month (hint: momentJS can probably help you with that), update all the calendars appropriately and fetch the right events to put in them. That should work, but as you can see it's quite messy. I can't think of any other method right now.

Comment: is there other method then, i have problems with duplicate events, so if 2 users or more work on the same day it shows only the first, and if i drag the first, the second then appears

Comment: @ADyson I tried with this one { views: {
        agendaFourDay: {
            type: 'agenda',
            duration: { days: 4 },
            buttonText: '4 day'
        }
    }}

Comment: and what was the result of that? Were you satisfied? It doesn't look like it would solve your problem. Like I said, what I described above are the only ways I can think of to try and solve this. As for your duplicated events, I can't tell you anything about that just from such a vague description, but it sounds unrelated to this question and you should probably make a separate question about it, if you can't resolve it.

Comment: i am not satisfied, i want 5 columns to work as one , so monday.tuesday.wednesday.thursday.friday.saturday.sunday, it shoulld all work as one field

Comment: @ADyson if you can understand me

Comment: No, not really. What do you mean by "work as one field"? They are 5 separate columns, so what is it that makes all of them be "one field" exactly? What behaviour does this imply or allow? It's not clear what this concept is or what you expect from it.

Comment: i atached a photo to see what i mean @ADyson

Comment: @ADyson as i showed in the photo

Comment: ok I thought you meant all the weeks were to be treated as one field. But yeah as far as I know basically you can't do what you want without either writing your own custom view or using one of the workarounds I mentioned above.

Comment: can you give me example for that @ADyson

Comment: For which approach? All of them are quite a lot of work and I don't have time right now to experiment. But for the approach using multiple instances of the calendar I think I have given a clear description of the building blocks of the solution. You can read the fullCalendar docs to find out which methods you need to use in order to manipulate the calendars and keep them in sync. Sorry I can't help further at the moment.

Comment: thank you @ADyson , sorry to bother you

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help as much as I have time for, which right now is to add a few comments to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Following changes worked for me, create custom view as follow,

```
views: {
            agendaFourDay: {
              type: 'agenda',
              scrollTime: '00:00',
              //type: 'basic',
              duration: { weeks: 5 },
              slotDuration: {days: 1},
              buttonText: 'M-Week',
              hiddenDays:[0,1,2,3,5,6],
              columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd M/D'
            }
        },
```

Following is my Output:
[Custom Week Calendar Using Fullcalender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbICi.png)